# Soundcloud/Soundmanager - eqData / waveformData returns null after toggling pause

Tags: javascript, sdk, soundcloud, soundmanager2

While using the javascript SDK, using the stream method it works perfectly, can use the 'whileplaying' function well. But when I seek (setPosition) or togglePause, it then breaks the use of eqData.

I have seen that is an issue to do with the crossdomain.xml upon repeat requests from the soundmanager class, but I was wondering if there was ever an effective fix for it?